# Candy Machine V2 Whitelist Settings

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I am working to set up my first minting site with Candy Machine V2 and have a couple of functionality questions I have not been able to find answers to:

1. Is there a way to define a date/time when the whitelist mint can begin? Right now it allows me to mint if I have a whitelist token anytime before the go-live date..even if that go-live date is a week away. So Candy Machine says the white list is 7 days away but I can still mint if I have a whitelist token. I only want white list minters to be able to mint one hour before the go-live date. How can this be done?
2. Can I set multiple white list time frames? So white list mint group #1 starts 2 hours before the public mint and then white list group #2 starts 1 hour before the public mint?

Help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this setting first:

```
    "whitelistMintSettings": {
        "mode": {
            "burnEveryTime": true
        },
        "mint": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "presale": false,
        "discountPrice": null
    }
```

this will only allow whitelist selling after the goLiveDate.
When you want to end the whitelist selling, make it public, update candy machine with:

```
"whitelistMintSettings": null
```

Don't delete it, just give a null value, otherwise the transaction will fail.

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I did. Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers to ur questions are on the official metaplex docs, on [configuration](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration) page.

1. You can set-up an starting hour for a Whitelist mint using the presale boolean inside the whitelist settings. If you set the presale to `false` then your CM will use the goLiveDate and will be live to be minted with ur whitelist settings token. You can check the last example that appear [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#whitelist-settings).
2. To do this you should play with [endSettings](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#end-settings), using this you will be able to do a temporally close of ur candy machine mint that can be resumed changing and saving the config file and then running [`update_candy_machine`](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/update) command from the  CMv2 CLI. So basically this can be done playing with endsettings and running `update_candy_machine` whenever you want to change something or resume the mint.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I set the presale to false, Now nobody can mint until the GoLive date is reached. But how can I allow only whitelist wallets to mint for that first hour of the GoLive rather then everyone being able to? I can't find any examples of setting a whitelist starting hour...In my case I need to allow only whitelist minters to be able to mint for the first hour and nobody else.

Comment: You cannot see the config like that but instead will have to update the config. E.g. set presale to true s soon as they should be allowed to mint with their token. The go live token is for the public mint btw.

Comment: That seems like a really risky alternative given you're relying on Candy Machine then last minute to update correctly with no issues, and then if it updates you have to push those updates to production. If there are issues the whole mint is delayed. Probably makes more sense to just write some custom code to disable the mint button and add a second timer showing time until whitelist mint. Which would be 1 hr before goLive date. Suprised that functionality isn't built in so I wanted to confirm if custom code is needed

Comment: Remember that UIs retrieve the state of the Candy Machine (CM) from the blockchain, so you just have to run `update_candy_machine` and the UI will be automatically detect the change doing an F5 or implementing an auto refresh every X seconds, also doing `update_candy_machine` takes a couple of minutes as max. Anyways if you want to see ur changes on chain you have to run `update_candy_machine`. In the case of using custom code on the front end will just stop the people that uses ur mint page, bots wont be stopped for example.